# Install PHP5 with Tomcat 7 on Windows?

Tags: php

Can't find anything on this, what are the steps or instructions for installing PHP with Tomcat 7 on Windows?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Tomcat?  IIS7+ allows for PHP to run natively.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's specifically designed to run Java Servlets so using it for PHP isn't normal. You could try using Quercus http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/. It's built for the Resin server but should work for Tomcat (although I haven't ever tried it out myself). Alternatively, if you just want to run some PHP scripts from a Servlet, you could try out the PHP/Java Bridge http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/.

A different approach that might work better could be to install Apache and use it as the web server for Tomcat instead of using it's own server. You could then run both Servlets and PHP from the same web server. The two wouldn't be able to communicate with each other directly but you might be better off using more indirect communication anyway.